# How to access module from main app in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a main Android App, called A and a module called B. I have imported the module and added the correct dependencies. My question is: how do I actually use the information from the module inside my Android App?
Do I just do B b = new B(); inside A? I think that this method is more related to accessing other classes within the same module. Is there a specific way to access modules that is different from accessing other classes within the same module?

Answer (score 0):

Am assuming your modules are Java Classes, just instantiate them the way you are proposing
 `b = new B();`

If those modules are Android UI elements like Activities/Fragments etc then you have pass an `Intent`to start them. Refer to Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityB.class);
 EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
 String message = editText.getText().toString();
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Similarly for an Android service (documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)):-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
startService(intent);
```

HTH